LMAX Disruptor check for available capacity
I wanted to check for the source code of LMAX's Disruptor:
private boolean hasAvailableCapacity(Sequence[] gatingSequences, final int requiredCapacity, long cursorValue)
    {
        long wrapPoint = (cursorValue + requiredCapacity) - bufferSize;
        long cachedGatingSequence = gatingSequenceCache.get();

        if (wrapPoint > cachedGatingSequence || cachedGatingSequence > cursorValue)
        {
            long minSequence = Util.getMinimumSequence(gatingSequences, cursorValue);
            gatingSequenceCache.set(minSequence);



            if (wrapPoint > minSequence)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

To my understanding, this code essentially checks if the slots the producer is requesting for has not been consumed by consumers even though it was populated previously. If this function returns False, it essentially means that the RingBuffer is full.
However, I have 2 questions:

Why do we need to minus the bufferSize from the cursorValue + requiredCapacity, and then compare it with the cachedGatingSequence which to my understanding doesn't have the bufferSize minused from it?
For the comparison of cachedGatingSequence and cursorValue, shouldn't it only return true if the cursorValue > cachedGatingSequence, which means that the producer is already in front of the consumer and we need to update the minSequence accordingly to check if the producer is indeed in front of the consumer?
In any case, the producer should never be in front of the consumer since the RingBuffer would be full in that case.

I tried debugging but couldn't get to debugging the Sequence numbers of the consumers.
